# Storing API data as state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, frontend

first and foremost, this is my first time posting on stackoverflow! I have seemed to run into a small, annoying problem that i just cant seem to figure out. Any assistance would be awesome.

Im trying to store objects from the api call within there own state so i can update the value once its set as state, and passed down to another component

Im fetching an API with Axios, and trying to store the data in state. I've stored it all in
`const [classData, setClassData] = useState([])`
but what i ultimately want to do is store a few separate pieces of state for the api call.
[What i get returned when i console.log the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beN0g.png)

i've tried storing the individual data like such
`const [vigor, set Vigor] = useState(data.data[0].stats.vigor)`
but i get an error, telling my vigor is not defined.

I've also tried
`const [vigor, setVigor] = useState(classData.stats.vigor)` but that feels wrong (using state to declare teh state of other items)

I'm fairly new to frontend development, so forgive me if my technical communication isn't amazing.

Here is my current code(main component):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Sd0c.png)

This is my axios utility:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96Im0.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't post pictures of code as it makes it hard to reproduce the problem.  Try to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You can use [snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers). You might also be interested in  [how to make React executable in a snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support)

Comment: Can you share the code so that can have a look. ?